# How to ensure the slider text stays under the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following page: http://jsfiddle.net/ybv4jd9d/

HTML:

```
<div class="box hidOverflow marginCenter">

  <div class="caption setLeft">
    <h3>This is Image One</h3>
    <p>This is a description or a start to the image one article...</p>
  </div>

  <img src="http://pagesbyz.com/n4n/theImages/banner.jpg" />

</div>
```

If the output pane is made smaller in the jsfiddle link, the text shows up and doesn't stay hidden.

How can I use `z-index` to make it go under the image so it doesn't show up and stays hidden.

Comment: I guess you can use a media query to target the smaller width and either just hide the div with display: none or make z-index: -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0vwm1vq0/

`.box { overflow:hidden; }` Will make the text invisible if it falls outside your image.

If you want the text to always be readable [within the grey area] you will need to use `media queries` to decrease the font size dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm adding an overflow to the box-div, the text hides itself when making the page smaller. 
So following is the solution to your problem:

```
.box {overflow:hidden;}
```